# Removing managed package version information from meta files

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, metadata-api, metadata

I have the same problem that is mentioned in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7709/how-is-the-presence-or-lack-of-managed-package-version-data-in-apex-and-vf-meta) question and while [Andrew's](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) answer explains WHY it happens, I would like to know: Is there any way to prevent/stop managed package version information from being added to the meta files of my Apex classes or visualforce pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE: 30th August 2013, Since Summer'13 Release**

- The platform now only includes package references in the metadata files when a actual explicit reference is made either in Apex code or VF markup. For this to take effect you may have to refresh from server and/or resave your files to API 27.0 at least.

A few thoughts, none of which are ideal I am afraid...

- If you can uninstall as manage of the packages as you can, obviously if they are not being referenced. Worth checking to reduce this if you can.
- Similar to above, but consider making a 'runtime' binding to the other package/s via Dynamic Apex or other such approaches that don't explicitly reference the other package components.
- Develop your code in a DE org that does have the packages installed. Assuming your maybe developing your code in an org where for other reasons you cannot uninstall the package.

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work for me because I have to use the pacakges and can't uninstall them. Just to clarify related to options 2 and 3, I am developing in a DE org that has the packages installed. The challenge comes when I share my code with other developers who might not have the same packages installed and get errors when trying to deploy it using the Force.com migration tool.

Comment: So while it might be painful, can you move to a new DE org for your develop, as per option 3? You may also want to consider sharing code via source control, that way you never store metadata files with these references in SVN and they remain clean. This second route is more work, but if you are doing more multiple developer development it is something you will likely have to consider in the future anyway.

Comment: We use git for source control but because I joined a team that was already committing the metadata files to the repo, I never thought about NOT committing them which is what I'll start doing from now on. Will that affect the deployment if another dev checks out the code and has to deploy without the metadata files?

Comment: You will still need them in the repo, just ensure as part of your code review / conventions not to allow them to be overwritten / committed.

Answer (score 2):

I built a python script recently that handles bulk editing of *-meta.xml files to set the correct version number for referenced managed packages.  The script could be pretty easily modified to handle your use case and requires only core python modules to run:

https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/scripts/set_dependent_versions.py

Our use case was to find a way to consistently set references to managed package versions.  We use a cfg file to store the version information and then run the python script after we release a new version of one of the 5 managed packages the package references.

I also built a Jenkins job that runs this script against each commit to make sure it doesn't find any changes (i.e. the developer forgot to run the script before committing the code).

As I'm becoming more familiar with Ant, I'll probably wind up rebuilding this functionality in Ant soon.

Comment: I've now completed the migration of this functionality into an ant macro.  The macro receives a directory, namespace, and version number as arguments and updates all meta.xml files in the directory which reference the namespace to the correct version.  [macro](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/lib/ant-salesforce.xml) and [xslt](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/lib/update_meta_xml.xsl)

Answer (score 0):

one simple solution is use salesforce online editor instead of doing code in eclipse. this resolved my problem.